# Code after call_user_func_array does not execute

Tags: php, call-user-func-array

So I stumbled upon something I didn't realise: `call_user_func_array` apparently interrupts the code, but doesn't get back to finishing the rest of it! In other words, it works as if to `return`, `break` or `exit` the current function it was called from, ignoring all code that follows.

```php
class B {
    function bar($arg1, $arg2) {
        $result = "$arg1 and $arg2";
        echo "Indeed we see '$result'.<br>\n";
        return $result;
    }
}

class A {
    function foo() {
        $args = ['apples', 'oranges'];
        echo "This line executes.<br>\n"
        $result = call_user_func_array(['B', 'bar'], $args);
        echo "This line never executes.<br>\n";
        echo "Thus we won't be able to use the phrase '$result' within this function.<br>\n";
    }
}
```

How can we return to and finish the rest of `foo`?

Comment: You've got a handful of problems with this code which mean it can't run as you've currently posted it (scope issues, a syntax error, and a deprecation warning), but there's nothing wrong with the execution flow once those are fixed: https://3v4l.org/I991I . Please post a reproducible version of the problem you're seeing, or we won't be able to help.

Comment: The Minimal Work Example wasn't exactly what I was working with, which had the error. It seems `call_user_func_array` does not behave the way I explained above. It's just that my `bar` function in my actual code had a problem. I'm dealing with a lot of code, and I'm not sure exactly what I did – but the idea is that I fixed the code in whatever function I was calling. I think we can safely close this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some changes to your code to actually make it work.

```
class B {
    static function bar($arg1, $arg2) {
        $result = "$arg1 and $arg2";
        echo "Indeed we see '$result'.<br>\n";
        return $result;
    }
}

class A {
    static function foo() {
        $args = ['apples', 'oranges'];
        echo "This line executes.<br>\n";
        $result = call_user_func_array(['B', 'bar'], $args);
        echo "This line never executes.<br>\n";
        echo "Thus we won't be able to use the phrase '$result' within this function.<br>\n";
    }
}

A::foo();
```

But after that it returned:

```
This line executes.<br>
Indeed we see 'apples and oranges'.<br>
This line never executes.<br>
Thus we won't be able to use the phrase 'apples and oranges' within this function.<br>
```

See: [PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74b6cd6133b04c1955a1fa4b8c0de3137694f661)

Please provide an example that does what you say it does.

Comment: Sorry! I ran into this problem in my code and tried to recreate a Minimal Work Example to post on here. I think the problem wasn't `call_user_func_array` after all – it was inside the `bar` function something broke (again, the MWE is not the exact code I was working with). It works like you say it does. My bad. :)